# Update GridView Based On Table Name From TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I think my question is quite straight forward.

Assume I have a gridview, a textbox and a button control in my .aspx page. What I want to do is pasting (or typing) the "**table name of my database**" into the textbox, and when the button is clicked the gridview shall display all columns from the respective table name only.

Thanks and regards

Update:
1. I forget to tell that I also need to allow editing, deleting and selecting command in the gridview.
2. Thank's for all the comments, I have tried few solutions. However I found out that the most practical way is to use DataSource (allow auto generation of insert, update, delete command). So far based on my research on Google, I haven't found any tutorials that can really teach using this method comprehensively.

My Current Code is like this:

```
protected void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
// sdsDynamic is the sql data source
// gvDynamic is the gridview
// txtTable is the textbox where the table name is contained           
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);
        string sqlText = "SELECT * FROM " + txtTable.Text;
        sdsDynamic.SelectCommand = sqlText;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlText, connection);
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        connection.Open();
        gvDynamic.DataSource = sdsDynamic;
        gvDynamic.DataBind();
        connection.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code block will satisfy your requirement:

In .aspx page, the gridview code may look like:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridViewData" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

In code behind the code may may use:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable("MyDataTable");
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(YourDBConnectionString))
{
    string sqlText = "SELECT * FROM " + txtTableName.Text;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlText, connection);
    adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    connection.Open();
    adapter.Fill(table);
}
gridViewData.DataSource = table;
gridViewData.DataBind();
```

Comment: Assuming the text box and button are already at .aspx page, thanks

Comment: bro thank's a lot this is working, can you tell me how to allow editing using this method also?

Comment: Change code in aspx for gridview like `<asp:GridView ID="gvData" runat="server" onrowediting="gvData_RowEditing">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>` 

And handle `RowEditing` event of the gridview

Comment: My friend thank you so much for helping. Actually, I have tried this. It's not practical to use datatable to allow editing / deleting. Since different tables will have different columns. Hence I prefer using DataSource that allows me to generate insert update and delete command automatically.

Answer (score 1):

How about just writing codebehind in the button click event to `select *` from the selected table name into a dataset, then bind the dataset to the gridview?

Comment: Hi, thx for replying. Is your method also applicable if I have sql datasource?

Comment: It should be if you just update the SelectCommand with the select statement. However, I have never used SqlDataSource, so there may be some tricks to get it working correctly in this scenario that I am not aware of.

Comment: Ok I nvr used dataset before and bind with my gridview. I usually use the datasource control. But for sure I will give it a try. Thanks a lot..

Comment: Hey, sorry for asking again. I also need to put the edit, select, and delete field into the gridview. Do you think it's practical enough to use Dataset achieving this?

Comment: I don't think you need to use a dataset if you have an SQL Datasource. To get the buttons in place, you can set the following properties on the gridView to true: AutoGenerateEditButton, AutoGenerateDeleteButton, and AutoGenerateSelectButton. I recommend taking a spin through the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx